# jq output into a non json list to use for a loop

Tags: json, shell, jq

I'm sure this has been asked, but I've searched and can't find anything to answer my question...

I'm looking for a simple way to output a json list as a non json list to process using a while loop.. Which means I need to strip the quotes, commas and brackets.. I know I could do it with `cut` but I'm sure I'm missing an easier way..

Say I'm using an aws command to get a list of resources and then I want to process that list in a while loop...

```
aws eks list-clusters | jq .clusters | while read cluster; do something; done
```

Something along these lines.. am I being stupid here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[]` to turn the list into a series of individual strings, and [`--raw-output` / `-r`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/) to output them without quotes:

> With this option, if the filter's result is a string then it will be written directly to standard output rather than being formatted as a JSON string with quotes. This can be useful for making jq filters talk to non-JSON-based systems.

```
aws eks list-clusters | jq -r '.clusters[]' | while read cluster; do something; done
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.